# iCloud Mail Rule

Tags: icloud, email

If I want the words "example", "test" and "demo" to be part of an iCloud Mail rule, do I have to add them separately or can I do it in the format shown below?

This screenshot is from icloud.com/mail.

[image]

Comment: Where is that layout from? It's not in Mac Mail Prefs or iPhone Settings & I don't see any way to enter rules on the web access. On the Mac, it's always been one 'match' per line, with an 'any'/'all' switch at the top.

Comment: This is what I expect a ruleset to look like in edit - this one looks like an Apple-added one, on a new M1 - https://i.stack.imgur.com/JvlDa.png

Comment: It’s from icloud.com/mail. Question updated.

Comment: Ah, found it. That looks to be a very simplified version of the Rules prefs. I have no idea if it can use a comma-delineated list. You might have to test it empirically.

Comment: Does the one built into the Mail app support it in this way?